# Deleting from a binary file

Tags: c

I am trying to delete an Employee from a binary file by marking it with a ' * ' at the first byte of the Employee.Firstname however if there is more than one employee on the file, and I try to delete the second employee by marking it for deletion with the '*' it will only mark the first byte of the first Employee.Firstname with  a ' * '.

Here is how I write to the file:

```
struct EmployeeInformation{

        char Firstname[32];
        char Lastname[32];
        char Address[32];
        char ID[8];
        char Duration[8];
    }

struct EmployeeInformation Employee;

void AddEmployee()
{
    FILE *fd;

    printf("\n\n>>Add Employee<<\n");

    //I use fgets and get all Employee info I just didn't include it for reading purposes.

    if((fd = fopen(BINARY_FILE, "ab+")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error in opening file.\n\n");
        getchar();
    }


    else
    {
        //Write Employee to file.
        fwrite(&Employee, sizeof(Employee), 1, fd);

        printf("\nEmployee Added!\n\n");
    }
    fclose(fd);


}
```

Here is the code for deleting the employee.

```
void DeleteEmployee()
{
    FILE *fd;
    char EmployeeID[8];
    long Pos = 0;
    fpos_t pos;

    printf("\n>>Delete Employee<<\n");

    //Ask user for ID of employee they wish to delete.
    printf("Employee ID:");
    fgets(EmployeeID, 6, stdin);

    if ((fd = fopen(BINARY_FILE, "rb+")) == NULL)
    {

        printf("Error, Cannot Open File.\n");
    }
    else
    {

        while(fread(&Employee, sizeof(struct EmployeeInformation), 1, fd) != 0)
        {

            if(strcmp(EmployeeID, Employee.ID) == 0)
            {
                    //Employee Found
                    printf("Employee Found!\n");

                    //Get Current Position in file.
                    Pos = fgetpos(fd, &pos);

                    //Go to that Postion.
                    fseek(fd, Pos, SEEK_SET);
                    //Mark for deletion with '*'
                    fputc('*', fd);

                    printf("Firstname: %s\n",Employee.Firstname);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Employe Not Found!\n\n");
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fd);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position you're getting from `fgetpos` is **after** the record you just read. You need to either call `fgetpos` before doing the read or subtract `sizeof(struct EmployeeInformation)` from the position before calling `fseek`.  You're also messing up the current position when you seek backwards and then write one byte. And finally, `fgetpos` doesn't return what you think it does; replace it with `ftell`.

I would suggest this:

```
long int pos = ftell(fd);
while(fread(&Employee, sizeof(struct EmployeeInformation), 1, fd) != 0)
{
    if(strcmp(EmployeeID, Employee.ID) == 0)
    {
            //Employee Found
            printf("Employee Found!\n");

            //Go to the BEGINNING of the record
            fseek(fd, pos, SEEK_SET);
            //Mark for deletion with '*'
            fputc('*', fd);

            printf("Firstname: %s\n",Employee.Firstname);

            //Now position back to the end of the record (-1 because we advanced 1
            //byte when we did fputc() above
            fseek(pd, pos+sizeof(struct EmployeeInformation)-1, SEEK_SET);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Employe Not Found!\n\n");
    }

    //We should now be at the beginning of the next record - mark the position
    pos = ftell(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
fseek(fd, Pos, SEEK_SET);
```

do

```
fsetpos(f, &pos);
```

... or something like that, most probably you have to subtract `sizeof(Employee)`.

Make sure that you seek to the right position, coming from the right variable, and containing the right value.

If your file is not too long, use `ftell` and `fseek` for positioning. Otherwise use `fgetpos` and `fsetpos`. Never mix these.

Answer (score 0):

since you are anyway are reading each individual record until you find the one you are looking for you could have a counter counting the number of records read, then when you find the one you want to delete just do

```
fseek( fp, (current-1)*sizeof(Employee), SEEK_SET); 
fputc( '*', fp );
```

then

```
fseek(fp, current*sizeof(Employee), SEEK_SET);
```

to position at the next structure since writing '*' will move the fp.